# How to (faster) find x value that minimizes result for function involving multiple LazyFrame columns?

Tags: python, scipy, python-polars

I have a LazyFrame with multiple columns of hourly data for a few periods. For each period, I want to find the x value for a function involving mathematical operations of multiple columns that minimizes the result.

I used scipy.optimize.minimize to accomplish this, and I actually obtain the desired result. The problem is that this process runs extremely slowly, so I'm just looking for anything that accomplishes the same, but faster.

```
    def minimization_target(x, period_start):
        return hourly_data.filter(pl.col('period_start') == period_start).select((((pl.col('price').median() * pl.col('quantity').median() - (pl.col('estimated_quantity') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum()) / (pl.col('key_product') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum())).abs() - 1).abs()).collect().item()

    results = hourly_data.group_by('period_start', maintain_order=True).map_groups(lambda group: pl.DataFrame({'x_values': scipy.optimize.minimize(minimization_target, group.get_column('initial_guess').median(), args=group.get_column('period_start').median()).x}), schema=None)
```

Minimal example:

```
import scipy
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

hourly_data = pl.DataFrame({'period': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'price': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 'quantity': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'estimated_price': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], 'estimated_quantity': [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'key_product': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8], 'initial_guess': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]}).lazy()
hourly_data = hourly_data.with_columns(pl.datetime_range(datetime(2024, 1, 1), datetime(2024, 1, 1, 23), '1h').alias('hour'))
hourly_data = hourly_data.with_columns(pl.col('hour').min().over('period').alias('period_start'))


def minimization_target(x, period_start):
    return hourly_data.filter(pl.col('period_start') == period_start).select((((pl.col('price').median() * pl.col('quantity').median() - (pl.col('estimated_quantity') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum()) / (pl.col('key_product') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum()).abs() - 1).abs()).collect().item()


results = hourly_data.group_by('period_start', maintain_order=True).map_groups(lambda group: pl.DataFrame({'x_values': scipy.optimize.minimize(minimization_target, group.get_column('initial_guess').median(), args=group.get_column('period_start').median()).x}), schema=None)
```

Input:

```
shape: (24, 9)
┌────────┬───────┬──────────┬─────────────┬───┬─────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ period ┆ price ┆ quantity ┆ estimated_p ┆ … ┆ key_product ┆ initial_gu ┆ hour       ┆ period_sta │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ rice        ┆   ┆ ---         ┆ ess        ┆ ---        ┆ rt         │
│ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64      ┆ ---         ┆   ┆ f64         ┆ ---        ┆ datetime[μ ┆ ---        │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆ i64         ┆   ┆             ┆ i64        ┆ s]         ┆ datetime[μ │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆            ┆ s]         │
╞════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═══╪═════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 4     ┆ 7        ┆ 5           ┆ … ┆ 0.9         ┆ 10         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 00:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   │
│ 0      ┆ 4     ┆ 7        ┆ 5           ┆ … ┆ 0.8         ┆ 10         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 01:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   │
│ 0      ┆ 4     ┆ 7        ┆ 5           ┆ … ┆ 0.7         ┆ 10         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 02:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   │
│ 0      ┆ 4     ┆ 7        ┆ 5           ┆ … ┆ 0.8         ┆ 10         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 03:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   │
│ 0      ┆ 4     ┆ 7        ┆ 5           ┆ … ┆ 0.9         ┆ 10         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 04:00:00   ┆ 00:00:00   │
│ …      ┆ …     ┆ …        ┆ …           ┆ … ┆ …           ┆ …          ┆ …          ┆ …          │
│ 3      ┆ 7     ┆ 4        ┆ 8           ┆ … ┆ 0.8         ┆ 40         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 19:00:00   ┆ 18:00:00   │
│ 3      ┆ 7     ┆ 4        ┆ 8           ┆ … ┆ 0.9         ┆ 40         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 20:00:00   ┆ 18:00:00   │
│ 3      ┆ 7     ┆ 4        ┆ 8           ┆ … ┆ 0.8         ┆ 40         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 21:00:00   ┆ 18:00:00   │
│ 3      ┆ 7     ┆ 4        ┆ 8           ┆ … ┆ 0.7         ┆ 40         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 22:00:00   ┆ 18:00:00   │
│ 3      ┆ 7     ┆ 4        ┆ 8           ┆ … ┆ 0.8         ┆ 40         ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 2024-01-01 │
│        ┆       ┆          ┆             ┆   ┆             ┆            ┆ 23:00:00   ┆ 18:00:00   │
└────────┴───────┴──────────┴─────────────┴───┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Desired output:

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ x_values   │
│ ---        │
│ f64        │
╞════════════╡
│ -16.006287 │
│ 10.331055  │
│ 25.420471  │
│ 37.352234  │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: It would help if you'd add example data and the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Avoid working with entire dataframe.**

As a start, you can cut the runtime by a factor of ~2 by only using the current group in the optimization target instead of filtering the entire dataframe first.

This can be achieved as follows.

```py
import functools

def minimization_target(x, group: pl.DataFrame):
    numerator_expr = pl.col('price').median() * pl.col('quantity').median() - (pl.col('estimated_quantity') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum()
    denominator_expr = (pl.col('key_product') * (pl.col('estimated_price') + x)).sum()
    return (
        group.select(
            (
                (numerator_expr / denominator_expr).abs() - 1
            ).abs()
        )
        .item()
    )

(
    hourly_data
    .group_by('period_start', maintain_order=True)
    .map_groups(
        lambda group: pl.DataFrame({"x": scipy.optimize.minimize(functools.partial(minimization_target, group=group), group.get_column('initial_guess').median()).x}),
        schema=None,
    )
    .collect()
)
```

**Simplifying minimization target.**

We'd like the minimization target to be as simple as possible as `scipy.optimize.minimize` will repeatedly evaluate the function. The current implementation works with "heavy" DataFrame objects and computes many terms common to all evaluations.

Using a simpler minimization target while precomuting these terms yields another ~4x speedup on top.

```py
import numpy as np

def minimization_target(x: float, s1: float, f1: float, s2: float, f2: float):
    return np.abs(np.abs((s1 - f1 * x) / (s2 + f2 * x)) - 1)

(
    hourly_data
    .group_by('period_start', maintain_order=True)
    .map_groups(
        lambda group: pl.DataFrame({
            "x": scipy.optimize.minimize(
                fun=partial(
                    minimization_target,
                    # precomputing terms common to all evaluations of the minimization target
                    s1=group.select(pl.col('price').median() * pl.col('quantity').median() - (pl.col('estimated_quantity') * pl.col('estimated_price')).sum()).item(),
                    f1=group.select(pl.col("estimated_quantity").sum()).item(),
                    s2=group.select((pl.col('key_product') * pl.col('estimated_price')).sum()).item(),
                    f2=group.select(pl.col("key_product").sum()).item(),
                ),
                x0=group.get_column('initial_guess').median()
            ).x
        }),
        schema=None,
    )
    .collect()
)
```

Comment: You can throw in numba to jit the `minimization_target`. That's low hanging fruit.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment to Herick's answer to offer a couple tweaks.

1. Use numba to compile the objective function
2. Don't reconstruct a new df for every group (ie. don't use map_groups)

As-is, I get a %%timeit performance of 35.5ms as the basecase

When I do #1 that drops to 32.9ms

When I do #1 and #2 that drops to 28.8ms

Start off with a couple helper functions:

```
import numba as nb

## This is a straight copy of Hericks's definition except it's
## decorated with nb.jit
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def jit_minimization_target(x: float, s1: float, f1: float, s2: float, f2: float):
    return np.abs(np.abs((s1 - f1 * x) / (s2 + f2 * x)) - 1)

#This is just a wrapper of the above that takes a dictionary and turns it
#into multiple args
def min_struct(x, struct_x):
    return jit_minimization_target(x, 
            struct_x['s1'],
            struct_x['f1'],
            struct_x['s2'],
            struct_x['f2'])

# The above has to be two functions because you can't compile a 
# function that takes a dict as input. You could do the 
# above as a lambda in the minimize call if 
# you wanted to but this seems cleaner

#This is another wrapper that takes the dict input and runs the minimize function
def optmin(struct_x):
    return (
        scipy.optimize.minimize(
            fun=min_struct,
            x0=struct_x['initial_guess'],
            args = (struct_x)
    ).x)
```

and then shaping the df to use `optmin`

```
(
    hourly_data.group_by("period_start", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        x=pl.struct(
            s1=pl.col("price").median() * pl.col("quantity").median()
            - (pl.col("estimated_quantity") * pl.col("estimated_price")).sum(),
            f1=pl.col("estimated_quantity").sum(),
            s2=(pl.col("key_product") * pl.col("estimated_price")).sum(),
            f2=pl.col("key_product").sum(),
            initial_guess=pl.col("initial_guess").median(),
        )
    )
    .select(pl.col("x").map_elements(optmin))
    .collect()
)
```